# Target exe for Android ABI(ndk build)

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, arm

I have an android system with two different CPU ABI - `armeabi-v7a and x64` .For which one I have to build the application code to get it working.My application (in c language)  anyway doesnt run for either of the platforms.
OR is there any common tool chain with which I can build the same.
arm-eabi-gcc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The NDK contains all the toolchains you need to run your program on Android platforms.

To setup the architectures you need to compile to, you should set the `APP_ABI` variable inside *Application.mk* or pass it to the `ndk-build` command.

`APP_ABI:=all` will make your ndk project being built for all the supported architectures: *armeabi*, *armeabi-v7a*, *arm64-v8a*, *x86*, *x86_64*, *mips*, *mips64*.

You can also list which architectures you want to build for: `APP_ABI:= x86_64 x86 armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a` and also use `all32` and `all64` as shortcuts to all the 32-bit and all the 64-bit architectures.

To determine which platforms are supported by a target device, you can call `adb shell getprop ro.product.cpu.abi` (preferred arch) and `adb shell getprop ro.product.cpu.abi2` (second arch).

Starting with Android 5.0, use `adb shell getprop ro.product.cpu.abilist` instead, that returns a list of all the supported ABIs, sorted in preference order.

Comment: so putting the output of adb shell getprop ro.product.cpu.abi in the APP_ABI:= <> should work right?Even the second arch is also fine?

Comment: Yes, exactly, and putting the first arch is better: on many x86 devices for example, the second arch is armeabi-v7a but armeabi-v7a binaries are actually executed through an emulation layer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can target completely different architecture (arm and x86) with android provided ndk (cross-compilers). You can target multiple ABI supported by arm with following variable

```
TARGET_ARCH_ABI
```

possible values are:

```
armeabi For ARMv5TE 
armeabi-v7a
```

for more details you can check this [link](http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/ANDROID-MK.html).

To run in x86 or amd64 system you can normally use a gcc to create the .so file and use JNI to test functionally (remember Android F/W will be unavailable there).

If you are looking for rapid building-testing cycle I think it's better for you to use an x86 based emulator like AndroVM (now Genymotion). In that way you can write code for android device and test it real quick.

Comment: That list of supported ABI is badly out of date. The latest one can be found in the NDK documentation. Open Start_Here.html, then navigate to "NDK Programmer's Guide" -> "ABI Management". The supported ABIs in R10C of the NDK are armeabi, armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86-64, mips, and mips64.

Comment: `TARGET_ARCH_ABI` shouldn't be rewritten, it's `APP_ABI` that should be configured. Also, many devices are actually supporting both x86 and arm architectures.